# want to know what kind of web-service I'm developing

Tags: node.js, rest

I'm working on Web-services with express framework and node.js.

My app.js is something like below:

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);
 var userService = require('./models/userService');

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.send('abc');
 });

 app.post('/movie',userService.getUserById);
```

And my `userService.getUserById()` is something like below:

```
 exports.getUserById = function(req, res){
     var data = JSON.stringify(
            {
                status:'1',
                data:'OK'
            });
     res.send(data);
 }
```

when I hit `http://localhost:3000/movie` with post method I'm getting `{status:'1',data:'OK'}` means it's working.

My question now is,

Is this a RESTful api ? why ?

Comment: I would not really consider this a RESTful api. Sure, you are handling both a GET and POST, but they are not related to each other.  A RESTful example would include the CRUD operations on a single model.  Checkout [express's docs](http://expressjs.com/starter/basic-routing.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraints for RESTful service are:

- Client–server - CHECK
- Stateless - CHECK
- List item
- Cacheable - CHECK
- Layered system - CHECK
- Identification of resources - CHECK
- Manipulation of resources through these representations - CHECK.  (no data can be modified/deleted, so should be considered conforming).
- Self-descriptive messages - NO. You need to add mimetype to response headers.
- Hypermedia as the engine of application state - CHECK. (no actions/state changes, so should be considered conforming)

So, no, this isn't RESTful service, at least until you start sending proper headers.
However, it is a bit funny to apply such a complex concept as RESTful service to this piece of code of yours. And if it is a school assignment I wouldn't recomend you give this to your teacher.

Comment: Thanks stroncium,
http://pixelhandler.com/posts/develop-a-restful-api-using-nodejs-with-express-and-mongoose

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

These are some blogs which i'd followed for learning stuff. Example in my question is small, but above are blogs according to which it's REST...how?

Comment: Well, as I said, the only thing different from rest is that you don't send Content-Type headers. After you do tart to send those it will become RESTful service. I'm not entirely sure about this blogposts, but I assume the way they send data to responses(directly calling send method on ServerResponse) adds this headers(and probably some more) for them.

Comment: Yes, only that. I've stated all criteria in answer.